# Find all real numbers $x$ such that $\sqrt{x+2\sqrt{x}-1}+\sqrt{x-2\sqrt{x}-1}$ is a real number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, radicals, alternative-proof

I want to find all values of $x\in \mathbb R$ such that the value of $\sqrt{x+2\sqrt{x}-1}+\sqrt{x-2\sqrt{x}-1}$ is a real number.

I solved it as follows:

$x+2\sqrt{x}-1\ge 0$

$(\sqrt{x}+1)^2-2\ge 0$

$(\sqrt{x}+1)^2\ge 2$

$\sqrt{x}+1\ge 2$ or $\sqrt{x}+1\le -\sqrt{2}$

The second can't hold, from the first $x\ge 3-2\sqrt{2}$.

Similarly $(\sqrt{x}-1)^2\ge 2$, hence $x\ge 3+2\sqrt{2}$.

I find my solution to be very ugly. Is my solution correct and is there a neater approach?

Comment: Is $x$ assumed to be a real number? Also, it doesn't make sense to write "$x \in$ the equation", because the equation is not a set for which the membership relation can be applied (excluding formalization of everything as sets as one can do in axiomatic set theory, of course). This is like saying "John belongs to pencil" ("pencil" is not a group of people for which it makes sense to ask whether or not John belongs).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro sorry for the error, I have edited it

Comment: I think this is exactly what was expected.

Comment: Ok nice thank you very much @RossMillikan

Comment: I edited so as to remove the unnecessary mention of a function and an equation.

Comment: I don't think that is particulary ugly.  I have a pet dog that is uglier.

Comment: haha:) nice one

Comment: I don't see why you would need $x + 2\sqrt{x} - 1$ to be nonnegative.  For example, if $x = -1$, then $\sqrt{x+2\sqrt{x}-1}+\sqrt{x-2\sqrt{x}-1} = \sqrt{-2+2i} + \sqrt{-2-2i} = 2^{3/4} (\cos(3\pi/8) + i\sin(3\pi/8)) + 2^{3/4} (\cos(3\pi/8) - i\sin(3\pi/8)) = 2^{7/4} \cos(3\pi/8)$ is real.

Comment: It's real for $x\le0$ or $x\ge3+2\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @Roman It is not true for $x\le 0$ because then the $\sqrt{x}$ in the equation becomes imaginary and not real

Comment: @MichaelBlane When you evaluate the entire expression, you'll find that the imaginary parts of the two summands cancel out at the end if $x\le0$. DanielSchepler gives an example.

Comment: @Roman I don't think it would work for $x = 0$.  But for $x < 0$, assuming you use the usual convention that the branch cut for the square root function is taken along the negative real axis (and along that axis, the square root is pure imaginary with positive imaginary part), then indeed $x + 2\sqrt{x} - 1$ and $x - 2\sqrt{x} - 1$ are conjugate complex numbers which are not negative reals, so their square roots are also conjugate, and so their sum is real.

Comment: @DanielSchepler alright, sorry about $x=0$, you're right. But it works for $x<0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement $x\ge0$ is obvious. The expression is real iff $(\sqrt{x}\pm1)^2\ge2$ for both choices of $\pm$, i.e. neither $\sqrt{x}\pm1$ is in $(-\sqrt{2},\,\sqrt{2})$, i.e .$\sqrt{x}\notin[0,\,1+\sqrt{2})\cup[0,\,\sqrt{2}-1)=[0,\,1+\sqrt{2})$, since $\sqrt{x}\ge0$. The solution set is $[3+2\sqrt{2},\,\infty)$, as in @alex.jordan's answer.

Comment: The requirement $x\geq0$ is not so obvious. If we agree on some complex-valued branch of the square root function, it's plausible that $\sqrt{x}$ is not real, and ultimately imaginary components of the two main terms (once again using that same complex-valued square root branch) cancel each other. At least it's not obvious that this won't happen. Or is it, and I am missing something?

Comment: @alex.jordan If we achieve what you propose in such a way that $\sqrt{z^\ast}=\sqrt{z}^\ast$, the two outermost surds will be square roots of conjugate pairs for $x\le0$, so will also be conjugate pairs, making the final result real. This would change the solution set to $(-\infty,\,0]\cup[3+2\sqrt{2},\,\infty)$.

Comment: @J.G. Well, if $z$ is negative real then it's impossible to have $\sqrt{z^*} = \sqrt{z}^*$ for any well-defined square root function - so $x = 0$ cannot work.  But otherwise, if you choose the branch cut along the negative real axis with image having argument in $(-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ (which as far as I know is the standard choice) then you do indeed get $\sqrt{z^*} = \sqrt{z}^*$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use Mathematica for an overview plot:

```
ReImPlot[Sqrt[x + 2 Sqrt[x] - 1] + Sqrt[x - 2 Sqrt[x] - 1],
         {x, -1, 7}, PlotPoints -> 10^3, 
         GridLines -> {{0, 3 - 2 Sqrt[2], 3 + 2 Sqrt[2]},
                       {0, 2 Sqrt[Sqrt[2] - 1], 2, 2 Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[2]]}}, 
         PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image]

- For $x<0$ the function is purely real.
- For $0\le x\le 3-2\sqrt{2}$ the function is purely imaginary.
- For $3-2\sqrt{2}<x<3+2\sqrt{2}$ the function has nonvanishing real and imaginary parts.
- For $x\ge3+2\sqrt{2}$ the function is purely real.